# Selenuim Python issue with getting elements in loop

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, beautifulsoup

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, "html.parser")
for h1 in soup.find_all('h2'):
    try:
        array.append("https://www.chamberofcommerce.com" + h1.find("a")['href'])
        print("https://www.chamberofcommerce.com" + h1.find("a")['href'])
    except:
        pass

input=browser.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@class="next"]')
while input:
    input.click()
    time.sleep(10)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, "html.parser")

    for h1 in soup.find_all('h2'):
        try:
            array.append("https://www.chamberofcommerce.com" + h1.find("a")['href'])
            print("https://www.chamberofcommerce.com" + h1.find("a")['href'])
        except:
            pass
```

This part of the code scraps urls of the listings on yellopages, the code worked fine until I used to scrap urls from only the first page of the search, Now I want it to click on next button until the pages of search finishes, Foe Example If there are 20 pages of search then the selenuim bot should click on next button and scraps url until it has reached the 20th page,

Please see the logic of the code, and also I am getting the following error after the bot reaches to the page 2 where as actual number of pages is 15 and it crashes on page 2:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`while input` is not what you need... Note that once you click Next button new page is loaded and all WebElements from previous page are no more valid: you have to re-define them on each page. Try below approach:

```
while True:
    try:
        browser.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@class="next"]').click()
    except:
        break
```

With above code you should be able to click Next button on each page while it is available. You might also need to apply [ExplicitWait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) to wait for Next button to be clickable:

```
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//a[@class="next"]'))).click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an explicit wait

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

...

t = 10 # Timeout

try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, t).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='next']"))
    )
except:
    # handle element not found or unclickable

element.click()

...
```